# Compare Object From Canvas with JSON String

Tags: javascript, json, canvas, fabricjs

Is there any way I can loop all objects present in my canvas and compare its JSON String with my stored JSON string If they are equal then Set Object as ActiveObject. 
Below Is the code I have tried but no successful results

```js
var datatocompare = '[{"type":"group","originX":"center","originY":"center","left":161.82,"top":76.48,"width":174.38,"height":59.05,"fill":"rgb(0,0,0)","stroke":null,"strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":10,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"backgroundColor":"","objects":[{"type":"line","originX":"center","originY":"center","left":0,"top":-0.01,"width":172.38,"height":1,"fill":"transparent","stroke":"transparent","strokeWidth":2,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":10,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"backgroundColor":"","x1":75.6300048828125,"y1":75.98500061035156,"x2":248.00997924804687,"y2":75.98500061035156},{"type":"rect","originX":"left","originY":"top","left":-86.19,"top":-30.03,"width":172.38,"height":59.05,"fill":"yellow","stroke":"red","strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":10,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":0.3,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"backgroundColor":"","rx":0,"ry":0,"x":0,"y":0}]}]';
for (var i = 0; i < canvas.getObjects().length; i++) {
var dummy = canvas.getObjects();
if(datatocompare == JSON.stringify(dummy))
{
canvas.setActiveObject(canvas.getObjects());
}
}
```